# agora call connecting but not hearing voice

Tags: call, voice, agora.io

We have a chat app, we are trying to integrate agora voice call feature, we are creating a channel and requesting token from our server using agoras token generator, after creating token we send it back to phone1 from our server then we start join channel in phone1 after that we send the token to phone2 using freebase, In phone 2 we receive token from firebase and run join channel method, but its not working, it says channel joined, but still no voice to hear from phone1

Please do guide us

Comment: Please share some code, and have set proper client roles?

Comment: It worked, got help from slack community, thanks for the response by the way, It got solved by using different tokens for 2 phones.

Comment: @NandagiriAkhilesh How you fix this issue? I have same issue. can you suggest an answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76170536/i-am-unable-to-hear-voice-of-another-user-in-agora-rtc-engine-4-1-0-alpha-2-voi