# I am unable to hear voice of another user in agora_rtc_engine: 4.1.0-alpha.2 voice call in flutter web

Tags: flutter, agora.io, agora-implementation, agora

I have integrated Agora Voice Call in Flutter Web using Accepted Answer of this question
[Is it possible to implement Agora Video Call in flutter web and flutter app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69032650/is-it-possible-to-implement-agora-video-call-in-flutter-web-and-flutter-app)

but the issue is I am not able to hear voice of another person. He or she can hear my voice.

Integration showing as below :

1. Initialozation

```
    agoraEngine =
        await RtcEngine.createWithContext(RtcEngineContext(agoraAppId));
    await setupEventHandler();
    await agoraEngine?.setAudioProfile(
        AudioProfile.SpeechStandard, AudioScenario.MEETING);
    await agoraEngine?.setClientRole(ClientRole.Broadcaster);
    await agoraEngine?.setChannelProfile(ChannelProfile.LiveBroadcasting);
    await agoraEngine?.enableAudio();
    _joinChannel();
```

2. setupEventHandler

```
agoraEngine?.setEventHandler(
      RtcEngineEventHandler(
          remoteAudioStateChanged:(int uid, AudioRemoteState state, AudioRemoteStateReason reason, int elapsed){
            print(
                "_VoiceCallingScreenState.setupVoiceSDKEngine: -> remoteAudioStateChanged uid $uid state $state reason $reason elapsed $elapsed");
          },
          remoteAudioStats:(statcs){
            print(
                "_VoiceCallingScreenState.setupVoiceSDKEngine: -> remoteAudioStats statcs $statcs");
          },
          firstRemoteAudioFrame:(int uid, int elapsed){
            print(
                "_VoiceCallingScreenState.setupVoiceSDKEngine: -> firstRemoteAudioFrame uid $uid elapsed $elapsed");
          },
          audioQuality:(int uid, int quality, int delay, int lost){
            print(
                "_VoiceCallingScreenState.setupVoiceSDKEngine: -> audioQuality uid $uid quality $quality delay $delay lost $lost");
          },
        error: (code) {
          debugPrint(
              "_VoiceCallingScreenState.setupVoiceSDKEngine: -> error ==> $code");
        },
        joinChannelSuccess: (String channel, int uid, int elapsed) async {
/*
          await agoraEngine?.setEnableSpeakerphone(false);
          await agoraEngine?.setDefaultAudioRouteToSpeakerphone(false);
*/

          print(
              "_VoiceCallingScreenState.setupVoiceSDKEngine: -> local user $uid joined $channel");
        },
        userJoined: (int uid, int elapsed) {
          print(
              "_VoiceCallingScreenState.setupVoiceSDKEngine: -> remote user $uid joined");
          setState(() {
            _remoteUid = uid;
          });
          startTimer();
        },
        userOffline: (int uid, UserOfflineReason reason) {
          print(
              "_VoiceCallingScreenState.setupVoiceSDKEngine: ->remote user $uid left channel due to $reason" );
          _dropCall();
        },
        leaveChannel: (RtcStats stats) {
          debugPrint(
              "_VoiceCallingScreenState.setupVoiceSDKEngine: -> onLeaveChannel => ${stats.duration} => ${stats.duration}");
          _dropCall();
        },
        connectionStateChanged: (ConnectionStateType connectionStateType,
            ConnectionChangedReason reason) async {
          debugPrint(
              "_VoiceCallingScreenState.setupVoiceSDKEngine: -> onConnectionStateChanged -> $connectionStateType reason ==> $reason");
          if (reason == ConnectionChangedReason.LeaveChannel) {
            _dropCall();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
```

3. Joining Channel

```
await agoraEngine?.joinChannel(
        rtcModel?.data?.senderRtcToken ?? '',
        rtcModel?.data?.channel ?? '',
        null,
        int.parse(rtcModel?.data?.senderUid ?? '0'),
        ChannelMediaOptions(
          autoSubscribeAudio: true,
        ));
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Voice call using agora_rtc_engine: 4.1.0-alpha.2 in Flutter Web with two-way communication